# OOXML/*.docx footnote discrepancy

Tags: xml, openxml, docx

I am parsing content from *.docx files outside the .NET environment and ran into what seems like a discrepancy between the XML MS Word produces and the OOXML spec. I'm hoping someone can explain what's going on.

I have a *.docx file with three document sections. The first has a footnote properties element like this:

```
<w:footnotePr>
  <w:numFmt w:val="upperRoman"/>
</w:footnotePr>
```

The second section has this (the numbering starts over in this section):

```
<w:footnotePr>
  <w:numFmt w:val="upperRoman"/>
  <w:numRestart w:val="eachSect"/>
</w:footnotePr>
```

The third and last section has no "footnotePr" element in the final "secPr," the section properties element that is a child of the body element and is supposed to govern the final section. According to the OOXML spec, in the absence of a "footnotePr" for the section, the global settings in the settings.xml should govern the appearance of the notes. The footnote properties element in the document settings file is this:

```
<w:footnotePr>
  <w:numFmt w:val="upperRoman"/>
  <w:footnote w:id="-1"/>
  <w:footnote w:id="0"/>
</w:footnotePr>
```

By the logic of the spec, it seems that the final notes should be numbered with roman numerals like the footnotes in the preceding section. In every copy of MS Word I open the document in, though, Word displays the notes in the final section with decimal numbering. LibreOffice displays them with roman numerals, like I'd expect.

Does anyone familiar with OOXML have any idea why this is the case?

For reference, the MSDN description of the "footnotePr" element and the corresponding documentation can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.footnoteproperties%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Specifically: "If this element is omitted for a given section, then that section shall use the footnote properties defined at the document-wide level."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word does what Word does...

[MS-OE376] and [MS-OI29500] both document some stuff about footnotes, but not your finding.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the standard helps to understand what comes out of the Word, but feeding the standard into the Word can produce unexpected results. In such a cases I usually make small incremental changes using Word and run a diff on a result.

In this particular case applying footnote property change to `Whole document` results in modification of not only global settings but also each section property. Which guarantee that once applied to document each section will have explicit value.

And more interestingly, applying `1,2,3 ...` numbering results in removing of `w:numFmt` either in individual section or all together.

It looks like there is a hidden default which we don't see in a document. In my case for `w:numFnt` it is `decimal` and for `w:pos` it is `pageBottom`. I wonder if it is language and/or locale specific.

I suspect other direction has a bug as well, a docx with default in settings set to `lowerRoman` and one section set to `decimal` will render wrong in OpenOffice - everything will be `lowerRoman`.